# pgAdmin4 login issue with postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I installed postgresql and edited pg_hba.conf with this configuration:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
host    all             postgres        all                     md5
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

I also made sure to able to login with `psql -U postgres -W` and I can login.

I installed pgAdmin4 but can not login via `postgres`. 
 It says: `Email/Username is not valid`

I searched for hours but did not find solution.

Ubuntu Server 20 LTS + Postgressql 14 
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Email/Username is not valid" comes on the login screen of pgAdmin web mode. It is different from PostgreSQL server login. You must have setup email and password when you setup pgAdmin web for the first time.
BTW if you have access to the pgadmin4.db file and dont remember the email/password, then you can remove the file from /.pgadmin/pgadmin4.db and start pgAdmin again.