# dockerised pgadmin4 refuses my login/password

Tags: authentication, docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a `docker-compose` with a web application, a postgresql database server, and pgadmin4. The `docker-compose` file sets `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` but they are refused at the pgadmin4 login window.

Here is the `docker-compose` excerpt:

```
  pgadmin: 
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: l.al@free.fr
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
    - "8081:80"
    volumes:
    - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
volumes:
  pgadmin-data:
```

If I `docker-compose down`, I cannot find any volume in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` as expected: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/pgadmin-data`.

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69975060/pgadmin4-login-issue-with-postgres), but not for a dockerized deployment. And thought, the `/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.db` file to suppress would have been in the volume.

What do I miss please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume I did access pgadmin4 and changed the login/password. In addition, the volume is not located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

I could find and suppress it with use of `Docker-Desktop`. Eventually, everything seems located inside `~/.docker`.